# Why won't my modifiers work in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am learning jetpack compose and I can't seem to understand why the the first value after my modifier will stay as an unnamed reference even after I import it.

The ".width" is what won't work albeit if it were to be deleted the    height wouldn't work.

Note: All imports concerning width etc are there

```
Text(
        text = "Johanthon",
        textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
        fontSize = 16.sp,
        textDecoration = TextDecoration.None,
        letterSpacing = 0.sp,
        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(100.dp)
            .height(21.dp)
            .alpha(1f),
        color = Color(red = 0f, green = 0f, blue = 0f, alpha = 1f),
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
        fontStyle = FontStyle.Normal,
    )
```

Comment: make sure you have a needed import, `import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width`

Comment: Import was there but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and just found out it was because I'd imported the wrong Modifier. I'd imported some java.lang thing. Make sure you've got `import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier`.

Hope your solution is something as simple as that!